# How can I wrap and indent strings from dictionary in Python output?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, format

I need help in wrapping my output text. I need to print the reference which is the book+chapter+verse number and the actual verse. However I need the line to wrap at 100 characters and then align with the first part already printed.

I have:

```
from operator import itemgetter

logfile = "kjv.txt"

def bible_read():
    fp=open(logfile,'r')
    store=[]
    while 1:

        line=fp.readline()

        if not line:
                    break
        if line[-1:] == '\n':
                    line=line[:-1]

        data0=line.split(' ')[0]
        data1=line.split(' | ')[1]
        data2=line.split('|')[2]
        store.append({'LINE':data0,'Chap':data1,'Verse':data2})
    fp.close()
    #print store[1]

    chapter = raw_input("Enter:")
    if '-' in chapter:
        book = chapter.split(" ")[0]
        w = chapter.split(":")[0]
        w = w.split(" ")[1]
        x = chapter.split(":")[1]
        x = x.split("-")[0]
        x = int(x)
        y = chapter.split("-")[1]
        y = int(y)
        #z = range[x,y]
        #print book, w, x, y
        chapR = range(x,y+1)
        for i in chapR:
            chapter = book + " " + w + ":" + str(i)
            record = next((item["Verse"] for item in store if item["Chap"] == chapter), None)
            print "%-10r %0r" % (chapter, record)


bible_read()
```

In this section:

```
        for i in chapR:
            chapter = book + " " + w + ":" + str(i)
            record = next((item["Verse"] for item in store if item["Chap"] == chapter), None)
            print "%-10r %0r" % (chapter, record)
```

I need to be able to print out like:

```
'gen 1:2'  ' And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon 
             the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of
             the waters. '
```

So I would like to get the output wrap at 100 characters and then indent so it matches up with the original indent.

Part of logfile:

```
2 | gen 1:3 | And God said, Let there be light: and there was light. 
3 | gen 1:4 | And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness. 
4 | gen 1:5 | And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day. 
5 | gen 1:6 | And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters. 
6 | gen 1:7 | And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so. 
7 | gen 1:8 | And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`textwrap` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) to wrap text at a certain linewidth, and optionally handle indentation.

To wrap lines at a certain width, then add your own indentation, you could use:

```
from textwrap import wrap

wrapped_lines = wrap(record, 100)
indented_lines = ('\n' + ' ' * 11).join(wrapped_lines)
```

This wraps your `record` text to 100 characters wide, then indents the whole text except the first line with 11 spaces; you end up with text 111 characters wide.

Comment: Python3 seems to provide an `indent()` method: `textwrap.indent(text, prefix, predicate=None)`